# Subdomains and IIS 7.5

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

I'm trying to set up  several web sites on my home server (running windows 7). Lets say ive got the domain `lol.com`. At this address I'm hosting some really lol stuff, but just for the kicks I've also want to have `mail.lol.com` that should lead into the webclient for the mail.

`lol.com` is hosted in `c:\www\www\` and `mail.lol.com` is hosted in `c:\www\mail\`. The default website (lol.com) is already redirected and works like a charm, but how do I config IIS 7.5 so it understands that when it gets a request like `mail.lol.com` it should redirect to `c:\www\mail\`?

`mail.lol.com` is a separate site I've created with its own physical path in IIS and it's binding is http(type) layout.localhost(host) 80(port) *(IP-address), but where do I do the actual checking of the request and redirecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your binding should be the same as address of your subdomain. mail.lol.com should have a binding with the same address. When a browser makes a request it sends a host header "mail.lol.com", that's how IIS knows which site to serve.

Comment: i've checked it, default web site looks like this: http(type) <blank>(hostname) 80(port) *(ip-address), mail binding looks like this: http(type) mail.localhost(hostname) 80(port) *(ip-address). IS THIS the way i should do it?

Comment: No, your hostname should be mail.lol.com instead of mail.localhost

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've got the site setup properly in IIS and you have the binding set to mail.lol.com, then the last step is to setup your DNS.

If lol.com is an actual domain that you have registered, you need to modify the DNS records for lol.com and add an **A Record** which points to whatever IP Address your IIS machine is listening on.

For clarification, an A Record is simply a record which ties a particular domain name to an IP address.  ([Wikipedia list of DNS Record Types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types))

If you don't have access to DNS records, or if this is just for machines in your home LAN, then you can achieve the same results by simply adding an entry in your local machines' host files.  The file is found at c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts.  For each machine, add a line with the hostname (mail.lol.com) and ip address of the server and you should be good to go.